# Como enviar via post em java uma informação para uma página php?

Tags: php, java, json

estou enfrentando um problema que no momento não sei como resolver.
Sendo direto, estou tendo problemas para enviar por meio de uma aplicação java os dados em json para uma página em php. Basicamente, eu tenho uma página em php que recebe os dados por meio do método POST e criei uma classe no java que envia esses dados via post. O problema é que no java eu não insiro o "identificador" que é solicitado na página php. Como podem observar, eu pego o valor na página em php pelo trecho de código `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user")` , só que na aplicação em java eu não insiro esse identiicador "user" na informação que quero enviar. Sendo assim, não tem como a página php "pegar" o valor que a aplicação java está enviando. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema? Desde já agradeço!

Página PHP:

```
<?php

    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
    $controller = new App\CWS\Controller();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $controller->cadastrarUsuario(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user"));
    }

?>
```

Classe responsável pela conexão e envio dos dados na aplicação Java:

```
public class WebClient {
    public String post(String json) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost//CWS//cadastrar_usuario.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.println(json);

            connection.connect();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            String resposta = scanner.next();
            return resposta;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar e receber dados crie essa class em seu projeto:

```
public class Conexao {

public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urlUsuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Envio
        OutputStreamWriter outPutStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
        outPutStream.write(parametrosUsuario);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();
        //Recepção
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         resposta.append(linha);
            resposta.append('\r');
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return resposta.toString();

    } catch (Exception erro) {

        return  null;
    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Para chama-lá em seu projeto faça:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "";
String parametros = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Se fosse um get bastava colocar no final da string url o ?nome=seuget
    url = "url do arquivo php";

    //parâmetros do post
    parametros = "texto=" + "123";

    new main.solicita().execute(url);

   }

    private class solicita extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

        //A string resultado tem os dados vindos do seu arquivo php

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "user=Joao";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Achei isso dando uma pesquisada.

Comment: Testei aqui e não funcionou amigo. Obrigado por tentar ajudar!